# "Persistent 'Set as Default' Warning Issue in Ubuntu 23.10 Browsers"

Tags: google-chrome, browser, default-browser, brave

fellow Ubuntu 23.10 user. I currently have two web browsers installed on my laptop:

1. Brave Browser (installed via snaps).
2. Google Chrome (installed from a deb package).

**Issue:**

Upon opening either browser, I consistently encounter a persistent "Set as Default" warning, irrespective of whether it's Brave or Chrome. This occurs even though I have already designated Brave as my default browser.

I kindly request a list of potential solutions if you possess any insights on this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands in a terminal:

```
cd /etc/profile.d/
sudo touch chrome-default-browser-check-disabled.sh
echo "export CHROME_DEFAULT_BROWSER_CHECK_ENABLED=0" | sudo tee -a /etc/profile.d/chrome-default-browser-check-disabled.sh > /dev/null
source /etc/profile.d/chrome-default-browser-check-disabled.sh
```

Then the "Set as default" notification should no longer appear when you launch Google Chrome.

To make these changes permanent, you can create a systemd service that sources the `/etc/profile.d/chrome-default-browser-check-disabled.sh` file on startup. To create a systemd service, create a file named chrome-default-browser-check-disabled.service in the `/etc/systemd/system` directory that contains the following contents:

```
[Unit]
Description=Disable Chrome default browser check
After=systemd-user-sessions.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "source /etc/profile.d/chrome-default-browser-check-disabled.sh"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Reload the systemd daemon configuration:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Enable the service:

```
sudo systemctl enable chrome-default-browser-check-disabled.service
```

Start the service:

```
sudo systemctl start chrome-default-browser-check-disabled.service
```

Maybe now the "Set as default" notification won't keep reappearing in Brave web browser either because it is designated as the default web browser in your Ubuntu.

If the "Set as default" notification still appears when you launch Brave web browser disable the "Set as default" notification in Brave web browser by using the above commands, but substitute `CHROME_DEFAULT_BROWSER` with `BRAVE_DEFAULT_BROWSER` and substitute `chrome` wherever it appears with `brave`.